# View model does not recognize extension method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods

I have a Html.GlobalisedPageLinks extension method in my view but get a redline stating my viewmodel does not contain the method and I have some invalid arguments?

here the line:

```
<div class="actions-left">
  <%= Html.GlobalisedPageLinks(Amico.Web.Mvc.Extensions.Enums.PageLinksFormat.Empty, Model.CurrentPage, Model.PageSize, Model.Total, x => Url.Action("Index", "Scorm", new { area = "Admin", page = x }))%>
</div>
```

the extension method:

```
public static string GlobalisedPageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, Amico.Web.Mvc.Extensions.Enums.PageLinksFormat format, int currentPage, int pageSize, int totalResults, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
{
  int totalPages = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)totalResults / pageSize)), 1);

  int startresult = ((Math.Max(1, currentPage) - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
  int endresult = Math.Min(startresult + (pageSize - 1), totalResults);

  string pagesText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.PageLinksFormatPages, currentPage, totalPages);
  string resultsText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.PageLinksFormatResults, startresult, endresult, totalResults);
  string firstText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.First);
  string previousText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.Previous);
  string nextText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.Next);
  string lastText = html.Resource(Resources.Global.PageLinks.Last);

  return "<span class='page-links'>" + html.PageLinks(format, currentPage, pageSize, totalResults, pageUrl,
    pagesText, resultsText, firstText, previousText, nextText, lastText) + "</span>";
}
```

what am i missing?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a using statement in your view to the class containing the extension method:

```
@using Amico.Web.Mvc.Extensions.YourExtensionClass
```

If you need to access this extension class in many views, you could also add the namespace for it as a known namespace in the web.Config inside your views folder (this example is for MVC3, host will be different for MVC4):

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="Amico.Web.Mvc.Extensions" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: my view folder does have a web.config but it is the main web.config that does contain that namespace so now i dont know :)

Comment: What happens if you add the using statement explicitly?

Comment: i can do that but boss will fail my code review if i do that! LOL let me ask him quick :)

Comment: You need to add the page namespace to the pages section within the Web.config in your views folder, not the main Web.config. See my updated answer - if you don't have that Web.config, you can add it :)